# Submit form if condition is true

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this form:

```
<form action="http://targatesite.com" target="_blank" method="post" name="xyz" id="abc">
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="user_email" />
      <input type="submit" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="user_value" class="user_class"/>
</form>
```

Suppose there is a variable **VAR**. The form can be submitted only when the value of **VAR** is **1**.

In detail On click on submit it will firstly check the value of **VAR** and if it returns **true** from will submitted and redirect to page given in action. And if it returns **False** it will show a message that **Please check value of VAR**

**Imp** VAR is not the field of form. We are getting this value from database.

Comment: One more amendment in question If VAR=1 the form should be successfully submitted. And if not it should show error that "check the value of VAR. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `onSubmit="return submit();"`

```
<form action="http://targatesite.com" target="_blank" method="post" name="xyz" id="abc"> <input type="hidden" name="email" value="user_email" />    
    <input type="submit" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="user_value" class="user_class" onSubmit="return submit();"/> 
    </form>
```

Try this Script :

```
 function submit(){
            if(var==1){
                return true;
           }
           else{
               alert("Please check value of VAR")
               return false;
           }
    }
```

Comment: One more amendment in question If VAR=1 the form should be successfully submitted. And if not it should show error that "check the value of VAR. "

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#abc').on('submit', function(){
     if(VAR == 1){
        return true;  
     } 
   alert('Please check value of VAR');
   return false;
});
```

This will work. The only thing you need to check is that `VAR` is in the scope of this function.

Comment: One more amendment in question If VAR=1 the form should be successfully submitted. And if not it should show error that "check the value of VAR. "

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var MYVAR=true;
$('#abc').submit(function(){
     if(MYVAR){
        return true;  
     } 
   alert('check the value of VAR');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: One more amendment in question If VAR=1 the form should be successfully submitted. And if not it should show error that "check the value of VAR. "

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can check VAR variable value from database,

when you have to submit form, you can code like this

```
if($_POST['sbmt']){
 $query = 'SELECT var FROM tablename';
 // here you can check var value
 if(VAR==1){
  //submit your form
 } else {
  $error_msg = 'Please check value of VAR';
 }
}
```

print this $error_msg whenever you want to show.

Comment: I did. It means the value of VAR comes from database, nothing more. How can you prevent submit with php?